# Some command in bootstrap script doesn't work

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, unix, amazon-emr

I am not able to read the file contents when i read the file in different user.
This is a simple bootstrap script

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -i -u hadoop bash <<EOF
echo "#################################"
echo "Logged In as user : "
a=$(cat /home/hadoop/Library.txt)
sudo pip install $a
EOF
```

Contents in **/home/hadoop/Library.txt**

mailer

elasticsearch

I even tried while loop but it gave the same empty result.

```
Result:
+ sudo -i -u hadoop bash
```

Comment: If by bootstrap script, you mean User data script, then you don't need to change any user. It executes as `root`. Just access the file  you want directly.

Comment: But why am i getting empty result ? can we not echo contents of file

Comment: yes, you can just `cat /home/hadoop/Library.txt` the file as root. Maybe the file does not exist or does not have content yet when you run the command?

Comment: it worked when i removed the switch user part. It won't work with switch user thing

Comment: So basically accessing it as a `root`?

Comment: by default the user is hadoop itselfso no need to switch user. :)... Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by changing the user in `User data` script. The solution was not to change it, and use the default user. In the case, the use is `hadoop`.